# rsync directory so all changes appear atomically

Tags: linux, rsync, files

I do some nightly and weekly mirrors of frequently used repositories for the local network.  On a few occasions, someone has tried to do an update while the rsync is happening and failed because the expected files aren't all there yet.

Is it possible to do an rsync such that *all* changed files only appear with the correct names at completion?  I know rsync uses temporary .hidden files while each transfer is in progress, but can I postpone the renames until it is finished somehow?

Alternatively it seems I could use the --backup option to move all changes to one directory and atomically move them after, but I'd want the feature to work in reverse to what it does now.

I'm on Linux for what its worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--link-dest=` option. Basically you would create a new folder, all files are hard-linked to the new one. When everything is done, you can just swap the folder names and remove the old one.

It is impossible to do this 100% atomic in Linux since there is no kernel/VFS support for it. However, swapping the names is actually only 2 syscalls away so it should take way less than 1 second to complete it. It is possible only on Darwin (MAC/OSX) with the exchangedata system call on HFS filesystems.

Answer (score 5):

I do something similar with `rsync` backups [to disk] and I've encountered the same problem due to a daemon updating files while the backup is running.

Unlike many programs, rsync has *many* different error codes [See the man page bottom].  Of interest are two:

> 23 -- partial transfer due to error
>   24 -- partial transfer due to vanished source files

When rsync is doing a transfer and encounters one of these situations, it doesn't just stop immediately.  It skips over and continues with the files it *can* transfer.  At the end, it presents the return code.

So, if you get error 23/24, just rerun the rsync.  The subsequent runs will go much faster, usually just transferring the missing files from the previous run.  Eventually, you'll get [or should get] a clean run.

As to being atomic, I use a "tmp" dir during transfer.  Then, when rsync run is clean, I rename it [atomically] to `<date>`

I also use the `--link-dest` option, but I use that to keep delta backups (e.g. `--link-dest=yesterday` for daily)

Although I've not used it myself, the `--partial-dir=DIR` may keep the hidden files from cluttering up the backup directory.  Be sure that DIR is on the same filesystem as your backup directory so renames will be atomic

While I do this in perl, I written a script that summarizes what I've been saying with a bit more detail/precision for your particular situation.  It's in tcsh-like syntax, [untested and a bit rough], but treat it as pseudo-code to write your own `bash`, `perl`, `python` script as you choose.  Note that it has no limit on retries, but you can add that easily enough, according to your wishes.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
# repo_backup -- backup repos even if they change
#
# use_tmp -- use temporary destination directory
# use_partial -- use partial directory
# use_delta -- make delta backup

# set remote server name ...
set remote_server="..."

# directory on server for backups
set backup_top="/path_to_backup_top"
set backup_backups="$backup_top/backups"

# set your rsync options ...
set rsync_opts=(...)

# keep partial files from cluttering backup
set server_partial=${remote_server}:$backup_top/partial
if ($use_partial) then
    set rsync_opts=($rsync_opts --partial-dir=$server_partial)
endif

# do delta backups
if ($use_delta) then
    set latest=(`ssh ${remote_server} ls $backup_backups | tail -1`)

    # get latest
    set delta_dir="$backup_backups/$latest"

    if ($#latest > 0) then
        set rsync_opts=($rsync_opts --link-dest=${remote_server}:$delta_dir)
    endif
endif

while (1)
    # get list of everything to backup
    # set this to whatever you need
    cd /local_top_directory
    set transfer_list=(.)

    # use whatever format you'd like
    set date=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`

    set server_tmp=${remote_server}:$backup_top/tmp
    set server_final=${remote_server}:$backup_backups/$date

    if ($use_tmp) then
        set server_transfer=$server_tmp
    else
        set server_transfer=$server_final
    endif

    # do the transfer
    rsync $rsync_opts $transfer_list $server_transfer
    set code=$status

    # run was clean
    if ($code == 0) then
        # atomically install backup
        if ($use_tmp) then
            ssh ${remote_server} mv $backup_top/tmp $backup_backups/$date
        endif
        break
    endif

    # partial -- some error
    if ($code == 23) then
        continue
    endif

    # partial -- some files disappeared
    if ($code == 24) then
        continue
    endif

    echo "fatal error ..."
    exit(1)
end
```

Comment: You seem to have a stray (or missing) `'"'` in `set backup_backups=$backup_top/backups"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi, David.  Yes, fixed. [but I did pre-qualify as "rough" ;-)]. But, thanks for following the link under my SO answer.  I've done other such links before, but you're the first one to provide positive confirmation that anybody actually follows them :-)

Comment: Oh yes, no big deal. I was actually curious how you set up your incrementals. I've used `rsync` to manage my office backups (well... since 2001 (or 2)), and I'm always looking at the different ways folks handle theirs. I like it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's quite similar. For multiple hosts: `set backup_backups="$backup_top/backups/<host_to_backup>"`.  The script is run on that host.  It first does `tune2fs -l` and uses "Filesystem state" to see if the FS has errors (i.e. needs `fsck`) and refuses to run if so. Each backup drive's name is a color (e.g. copper, indigo, etc.). I fire a launcher on each system and they set a time (e.g. 10:09 --> 10:15) so they all fire at exactly the same time (gives owner time to remount with noatime). That way, when all done, each system has exact same timestamp for backup

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The launcher fires rsync in an xterm window with backround color of drive's color. It's pretty, but I have two systems and four bkup drives, so if I say bkup all sys on all drives, it helps.  The common timestamp allows for "state of the world" at time X.  I don't do it, but multiple drive rotation to offsite safe deposit box. Do backup [from all systems] to given drive for given day [rotate].  Eventually, drives have like N months of deltas.  Occasionally, rm the older ones for space. I use WD-MyBook (4TB) USBs, so I've gone a year without needing to rm for space.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's whole system backup.  But, the script also cherry picks mission critical documents (e.g. turbotax files, source code, git repos, passwd files, email folders, etc.) to a USB thumb drive [or two] that I keep on my keychain. Had a fire locally here two years ago [_nobody_ was hurt] that got within 90 feet of my front door, so that's when I started the thumb drive backups. Now, I print any receipt (etc.) to folder as pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is going to help you, but...

If you don't mind copying the whole data set each time **and** if you can use symlinks to refer to the target directory, then you should be able to rsync everything into a temporary directory and then swap (*rename()*) the old and new symlinks atomically, like so:

```
% mkdir old_data new_data
% ln -s old_data current
% ln -s new_data new
% strace mv -T new current
```

which runs

`rename("new", "current")`                = 0

and gives

```
current -> new_data
```

Even for this to work any clients trying to read from this setup should `cd` into the directory referenced by the symlink before attempting any reads, otherwise they risk loading some parts of code/data from the old copy and some from the new one.

Comment: I use a similar algorithm (copy to a new directowy + change symlink named *current*) with my PHP web applications installation script, including on production servers. This is a fine solution which allows for minimal downtime and completely atomic procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Are the mirror syncs automatic (a *cron* task or like)? If so, you probably use a dedicated OS user for this, am I right? So the solution could be, instead of simply copying:

1. Set destination directory permissions so only *rsync* will be able to access it.
2. Proceed with syncing.
3. Change target's permissions (unconditionally) so the others can access it again.

The downside is that during the sync process (not sure how long it takes) the target directory won't be accessible. You need to decide yourself if it's OK here.